# MongoDb connection timeout

Tags: c#, mongodb, desktop-application, firewall, windows-firewall

I am using mongoDb for desktop application. it works when I uses home WIFI but when I uses my company WIFI , it get connection timeout error

I checked firewall and it seems it doesn't block it. how can i solve this?

exception :

```
 System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occurred after 30000ms 
selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
 MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, 
LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is {
 ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet",
 State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, 
EndPoint : "Unspecified/xxxxxxxxxx" }", EndPoint:
 "Unspecified/xxxxxxxx", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: 
"Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
 HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An 
exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
 because the connected party did not properly respond after
 a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
 host has failed to respond 207.46.145.150:27017
```

[image: Full Exception details]

Comment: you should provide full exception

Comment: I added the full exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, finally I found that there is a white list you need to configure to allow the access of the mongodb.

See this documentation:

[Configure IP Access List Entries](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#std-label-access-list).